# Extending FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Tags: android, fragment

I have my application code base with multiple activities in it. I have a `BaseActivity` class which extends `Activity` class and is the parent class for all Activities in my application. `BaseActivity` takes care of the state my application goes in background and comes back to foreground.
Now I have written few more Activities which are using `fragments` so these new Activities are extending `FragmentActivity`. But my application design requires that all activities should extend `BaseActivity` class.

Solution in my mind:

- BaseActivity extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity class.
- New activities(with fragments) extend BaseActivity instead of directly extending FragmentActivity.

With this solution I am afraid of any side effect in my existing activities which were extending `Activity` class (through `BaseActivity`). Now these activities will extend `FragmentActivity` (although they are not having fragments inside).
Is it okay if I extend `FragmentActivity` even though I dont have any fragment inside. Will it behave same as Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as `FragmentActivity extends Activity` so looks it's fine.jsut you need to add compitiblilty library if want to give the support for old versions

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Even I did same and found no side effect yet

Comment: I am unable to use startActivity(intent); in FragmentActivity ? after changing Activity to FragmentActivity.

Comment: Has anyone found any side effects of switching to subclassing FragmentActivity in your BaseActivity as of yet?